# How to set up OpenSSH (server) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssh, openssh, sshd

What is the proper way to install OpenSSH (using the latest binary from mls-software) on Windows 7 and configure it to enable remote users to connect via password of public key authentication?

I installed it and I'm able to ssh to `localhost` from the Windows machine itself but I'm unable to ssh from a remote (OSX) machine. Using the local ip address of the Windows machine (instead of `localhost`) works as well - only on the Windows machine itself.

Output of `ssh -V` on Windows machine:

```
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

Output when trying to ssh from a remote machine (fails): http://pastebin.com/3sryrEt3

Output when using ssh from the Windows machine itself (works): http://pastebin.com/zhXiJCHs

I didn't make any changes to the default sshd config that comes with this version of OpenSSH.

Comment: You probably need to open an incoming port in your firewall.

Comment: It looks like when you got it to work locally, you were not actually using public key encryption.   I can see the part of the log where it is prompting you for a password.

Comment: Also, if you look at either log, you will notice that SSH is looking for your public key files in `/home/username/.ssh` which is not going to work in Windows seeing as there is no `home` folder.   This is how Linux has the users folders configured.    You need to edit the ssh.conf (or whatever it is called in the windows port of SSH) and modify it to point to the directory that contains your public key file that you generated in order to get the public key auth working.   On Mac, you will need to generate a key locally and then import it into the authorized_keys file in the .ssh directory.

Comment: Did you know that Microsoft is working on its [port of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH)? See also [my guide for setting it up](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).

Comment: Hmm... in the ssh from Windows machine log, look at line 126 to 155.   Why does it show the public key auth failing, but above line 126 it shows the public key auth working.   Did you make any changes in between sessions from when those logs were created?

Comment: @Richie086 I don't need to use public key authentication - the problem is it does not fallback to password authentication after it tries my keys

Comment: @Richie086 public key auth can't succeed because authorized_keys does not even exist. I'm not worried by that but by the fact that it does not ask me for password when I try to log in remotely.

Comment: tried disabling `ssh-agent` and using ssh with default config (and no keys) on remote machine, still not working

Comment: @BenN The OpenSSH installer has created 3 firewall rules - one is for port 22, not sure about the role of the other 2

Answer (score 0):

I researched this for hours a while ago. In order to get OpenSSH server and OpenSSH client working in Windows 7 you will need:

- Cygwin installed
- to add OpenSSH to Cygwin
- to change the settings/whatever on Cygwin and maybe other stuff

See this tutorial for more info, 2012 video titled "Install OpenSSH in Windows 7":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHAEsUL6rsw

Within Cygwin, I found that it was easy to get ssh working in this direction:

- Windows 7 computer -> ssh into a Linux computer on the same local network

but difficult to get to work in this direction:

- GNU/Linux computer -> ssh into a Windows 7 computer on the same local network

but it seems like that YouTube video and stuff has the details on how to do it. I didn't get the chance to confirm since a computer of mine died, but it looks like that video contains the solution. Also, I guess Cygwin is available and works on Mac or OSX.